# Independent vector fields $X,Y$ on $S^3$ with $[X,Y]=Y$

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds

Are there two smooth independent vector fields $X,Y$ on $S^3$ with  $[X,Y]=Y$?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

No.  If such a pair existed, they would be tangent to a codimension $1$ foliation of $S^3$.  Such a foliation must have a Reeb component, in particular, a compact leaf, $T\subset S^3$, which would be a torus (since its tangent bundle would be trivial).  If $\xi$ and $\eta$ were the $1$-forms on $T$  dual to the basis $X$ and $Y$ of its tangent bundle, then the above equation would imply that $\mathrm{d}\eta = \eta\wedge\xi$, but this would make a nonvanishing $2$-form on $T$ have vanishing cohomology class in $H^2(T,\mathbb{R})$ (de Rham cohomology), which is clearly impossible.

Answer (score 5):

You can also use this result which appears in the following paper of E. Ghys see corollary I.1.2: Let $G$ be a Lie group homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^n$ which acts locally freely on a $n+1$-dimensional manifold $M$. Then the universal cover of $M$ is diffeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$.

The vector field $X,Y$ define an action of $Aff(\mathbb{R})$ on $S^3$, but the universal cover of $S^3$ is $S^3$ and not $\mathbb{R}^3$.

http://perso.ens-lyon.fr/ghys/articles/actionslocalement.pdf

Comment: Thank you for  your  answer and the  reference to the  Paper of Etienne Ghys. But  just a question: We  do not have $[X,Y]=0$ so how  do you  consider an action of  $\mathbb{R}^2$  on  $S^3$?

Comment: It is the action of the affine group of the line $Aff(\mathbb{R})$ which is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^2$ as a manifold, but is not isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^2$ as a Lie group.

Comment: The conclusion of Ghys's theorem should of course be that the universal cover of $M$ is diffeomorphic to $\mathbb R^{n+1}$, not $\mathbb R^n$.

Comment: @TsemoAristide  Thanks  again  for  introducing the  paper  of  E. Ghys.